# How to apply convolution on a buffer

Tags: audio, convolution, filtering

I'm trying to do some simple filtering for an audio signal using a window-sinc low pass filter. Supposing that my buffer has M values and the filter kernel size is N, after convolving these two arrays I would obtain an output of m+n-1 values. Which part should I take into consideration? I'm asking this because, if I read a M values array I should write a M values array. I have tried to take the first M or the last M values for output, but the result is not too good. I was wondering if I have to use a circular buffer in which I put every time M+N-1 values, but I read the first M values.

Comment: Are you performing one-shot filtering of single sample buffers, or are you going to be filtering an arbitrarily long signal one block at a time?

Comment: Practically, I read a .wav or a .mp3 chunk by chunk, I do some filtering (like in winamp or in other player) and after that I play it.

Comment: OK, then in that case you need to make sure you maintain the state of the filter between blocks, as Hilmar's answer below suggests.

Answer (score 3):

- Output the first M samples of your convolution result
- Keep the remaining samples and ADD those to the result next buffer

Google "overlap add" for more information. While overlap add is a frequency domain method, it explains the framing and buffer handling well.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I have another question regarding recursive biquad filters. In this case, I need to store only out[i-1],out[i-2],in[i-1],in[i-2]. I am asking this because convolution is practically hidden behind the recursive formula. The problem is that I hear some "high frequency cracks". I've also created a post with this issue, but their solution didn't work. http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/strange-noises-when-filtering-audio-signal I know that I was making a big mistake: the for loop should be placed after computing out[0] and out[1], but this change doesn't help me.