# Low Pass Filter Artifacts

Tags: audio, lowpass-filter

I have created a Low Pass filter (I am trying to understand the topic of DSP, and it's hard.. But moving along with samples, books and a nice post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479785/low-pass-audio-filter-calculating-rms-on-ios)).

I am saving the 'output' to a file, and I hear a constant clicking noise (very rapid, medium-pitch). The volume (intensity) of the 'clicking' gets louder as there is more intensity (in the passband of my filter).

I have been reading something about possible Artifacts when designing filters (FIR), but I am wondering if this is the constant clicking noise I hear ? It's not bad for my system, because I try to measure the intensity of the 0..100Hz band, and the clicking increases when the low sound increases. But I am just wondering if it's bad, or a possible symptom of a flaw in my filter ?

Thanks!

My Filter (of-course the getLPCoefficientsButterworth2Pole() is called first):

```
double ax[3];
double by[3];
double xv[3];
double yv[3];

void getLPCoefficientsButterworth2Pole(const int samplerate, const double cutoff, double* const ax, double* const by)
{
double PI = M_PI;
double sqrt2 = sqrt(2);

double QcRaw  = (2 * PI * cutoff) / samplerate; // Find cutoff frequency in [0..PI]
double QcWarp = tan(QcRaw); // Warp cutoff frequency

double gain = 1 / ( 1 + sqrt2 / QcWarp + 2 / ( QcWarp * QcWarp ) );

by[2] = ( 1 - sqrt2 / QcWarp + 2 / ( QcWarp * QcWarp ) ) * gain;
by[1] = ( 2 - 2 * 2 / ( QcWarp * QcWarp ) ) * gain;
by[0] = 1;

ax[0] = 1 * gain;
ax[1] = 2 * gain;
ax[2] = 1 * gain;
}

void process(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount numberFrames,
         MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags, AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut,
         CMItemCount *numberFramesOut, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut)
{
OSStatus err = MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut,
                                                  flagsOut, NULL, numberFramesOut);

if (err)
    NSLog(@"Error from GetSourceAudio: %ld", err);

float leftVolume, rightVolume;

NSLog(@"Test: %f", xv[1]);

for (CMItemCount i = 0; i < bufferListInOut->mNumberBuffers; i++) {
    AudioBuffer *pBuffer = &bufferListInOut->mBuffers[i];
    int cSamples = numberFrames * pBuffer->mNumberChannels;

    float *pData = (float *)pBuffer->mData;
    float rms = 0.0f;

    for (int j = 0; j < cSamples; j++) {

        xv[2] = xv[1];
        xv[1] = xv[0];

        xv[0] = pData[j];
        yv[2] = yv[1];
        yv[1] = yv[0];

        yv[0] =   (ax[0] * xv[0] + ax[1] * xv[1] + ax[2] * xv[2]
                   - by[1] * yv[0]
                   - by[2] * yv[1]);

        pData[j] = 20 * yv[0];
        rms += yv[0] * yv[0];

    }

    if (cSamples > 0) {
        rms = sqrtf(rms / cSamples);
    }

    if (0 == i) {
        leftVolume = rms;
    }

    if (1 == i || (0 == i && 1 == bufferListInOut->mNumberBuffers)) {
        rightVolume = rms;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post a plot of the output.

Comment: "plot of the output" ? Remember that I am a newbie :)

Comment: Can you graph the output samples you are saving to a file?

Comment: A screenshot of a spectrum analyses you mean ? Remember it's an audio file.

Comment: No, I mean a screenshot of the time-domain signal.  The clicking noise you are hearing is time-domain, so we need to see what is happening there not in the spectrum. Can you upload the audio file somewhere to share?

Comment: https://soundcloud.com/niek-van-der-steen/low-pass-filter-sample Maybe you can hear it's the first few seconds of the Sintel movie :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the audio clip posted on soundcloud, it looks like there's a discontinuity in the output every ~2060th sample. I suspect that you process your audio stream by blocks and that you do not save/restore the state variables of your filter between each call to the filtering function - so every time you process a new chunk of audio it is as if it was preceded by zeros - which is not the case obviously.

[Related question.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/strange-noises-when-filtering-audio-signal/8273#8273)

Comment: As you can see, my filter vars are 'global' and thus saved. Am I missing something here ? (added my filter code right now)

Comment: You were right. I forgot (of-course) that I also have a left and right channel, and those were mixing up now... But I still have a lot of high sounds left in my sound now.... So it doesn't look like my filter's working ?

Answer (score 3):

Common causes of clicking sounds in filter output are [clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28audio%29) and [accumulator overflo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974336/fixed-point-fir-filter-output-size)w (the numbers your filter is summing together are integers and go larger than the largest possible integer stored on your device).

Having a plot (or the actual samples) of the output would help identify which issue (of these or others not mentioned) it is.

---

**EDIT:** Thanks for uploading!

It's not clear *why* these are happening, but it seems like your filter implementation is inducing the clicks.  This plot shows a zoomed-in look towards the start of the signal.  There are many tiny glitches that I do not believe should be there and these are the clicks that can be heard.

Is it possible to share you low pass filter implementation?

[image]

Comment: I've posted the sample on SoundCloud. https://soundcloud.com/niek-van-der-steen/low-pass-filter-sample (it's the first few seconds of the Sintel movie)

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen What does the data look like before it goes into the filter?

Comment: Another common source of issues like this is the incorrect handling of filter state between blocks when performing block-oriented processing. I would guess that's the problem.

Comment: or off-by-one errors in your block sizes?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am looking into my Block interpretation right now, I updated my original question with the filter I use. What tool do you use to analyse the audio like that ?